# Glassfish 3.1 + MyFaces - ClassFormatError

Tags: jsf, glassfish, myfaces

I am trying to override Mojarra in Glassfish with MyFaces. I have put **myfaces-impl** dependency in maven and removed the RI dependencies - **jsf-api.jar** and **jsf-impl.jar**. I've also asked Glassfish nicely to use bundled JSF implementation as shown in [here](http://old.nabble.com/MyFaces-on-Glassfish-3-td31763259.html) using these lines in **glassfish-web.xml**:

```xml
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/Grandis</context-root>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
    <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

However, when I try to deploy the application I get the following error:

```xml
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1486)
```

I also tried downloading MyFaces jars(**myfaces-2.1.3.jar**, **myfaces-api-2.1.3.jar**, **myfaces-bundle-2.1.3.jar** and a bunch of apache commons libraries) manually and putting them in the classpath of application. Same result.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Posting the contents of WEB-INF/lib inside WAR when I add dependency through maven (excluding only my own jars):

```xml
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
javaee-api-6.0.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
myfaces-api-2.1.3.jar
myfaces-impl-2.1.3.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.0.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.0.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.0.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.0.0.jar
prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0.jar
primefaces-3.0.M4-SNAPSHOT.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.3.1.jar
```

Comment: Please list the JARs which have ended up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the WAR build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your JAR listing in `/WEB-INF/lib`:

> - javaee-api-6.0.jar

Remove this. Not only Glassfish *already* ships with it (I don't do Maven, but from what I've read is that you should mark it as `provided`), but this also contains Mojarra (the JSF reference implementation) libraries as well which in turn explains your problem. It was conflicting with MyFaces libraries.

Further, Glassfish also *already* ships with JPA and JSTL (1.2!), so remove them from the build as well.

> - jstl-1.1.2.jar
> - org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.0.0.jar
> - org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.0.0.jar
> - org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.0.0.jar
> - org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.0.0.jar
> - standard-1.1.2.jar

Comment: Thanks! I admit, I did know that glassfish provides all these but did not think they were JSF related to try removing them. The app has deployed and although I'm getting ViewExpired exceptions every postback and PrettyFaces fails to inject url parameters into beans im one step closer to the target :)